# Worklight: How to disable reports database

Tags: database, report, ibm-mobilefirst

I am not using reports database in my WL application. Now I want to disable the Reports database, how i can do it?

One way is to **disable the report data-source on WAS**. But I am not sure what impact it can produce on the WL run time libraries.

The purpose is to optimize server db connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `worklight.properties` file, make sure all reports-related properties are commented out.

Comment: ah, right that's the correct point. but i was under false impression that it may cause problems. Thaks